# Composition series for direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find all the composition series for $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. In order to write down composition series for $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ we have to find maximal normal subgroup. I was able to write down the following three series:
$$S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \vartriangleright A_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \vartriangleright\{e\}\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \vartriangleright\{e\}\times \{e\},$$
$$S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \vartriangleright S_3\times \{e\}\vartriangleright A_3\times \{e\} \vartriangleright\{e\}\times \{e\},$$
$$S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \vartriangleright A_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \vartriangleright A_3\times \{e\} \vartriangleright\{e\}\times \{e\}.$$

But I am not sure did I write down all maximal normal subgroups for $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Can anyone explain in detail how to find all maximal normal subgroups is this case? For example, I can find normal subgroups for $S_3$ using conjugacy classes and for $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But how to apply it for $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: There is another subgroup of index $2$ that you missed: note that $A_3\times\{e\}$ is normal, and the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$, so by the correspondence theorem, there should be three intermediate subgroups.

Comment: I understood the most part of your comment but let me ask you some questions which I was not able to answer by myself. Since $A_3\times\{e\}$ is normal in $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $(S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2)/(A_3\times\{e\})\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and the Klein 4-group has 3 proper nontrivial subgroups namely $\langle a\rangle$, $\langle b\rangle$ and $\langle ab\rangle$. But I have difficulties to "recover" these subgroups between $A_3\times\{e\}$ and $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. I know the correspondence theorem but not able to use it properly.

Comment: Could you show this realization in detail?

Comment: Yes. Suppose that $a$ is an element of order $2$ in $S_3$, and $b$ is the generator of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factor, then $ab$ is an element of order $2$, and together with $A_3$, they generate a group of index 2.

Comment: It's exactly the same as in your comment: you start with $A_3$, then add $a$, $b$, or $ab$. In the first case, you get $S_3$, in the second case $A_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and in the missing case, some kind of mixed diagonal subgroup.

Comment: Note that this last subgroup is actually isomorphic to $S_3$ (check this!), so it has a unique composition series.

Comment: I did not understand the point when you considered elements $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Just give a name to your elements. Write $S_3=\langle c,a\rangle$, where $a$ has order $2$ and $c$ has order $3$, and $Z_2=\langle b\rangle$. Now $S_3\times Z_2=\langle a,b,c\rangle$. The three subgroups of index $2$, are $\langle c,a\rangle$, $\langle c,b\rangle$ and $\langle c,ab\rangle$. (Just like the three subgroups of $\langle a,b\rangle$ are $\langle a\rangle$, $\langle b\rangle$ and $\langle ab\rangle$, as you said yourself.)

Comment: @verret, Honestly to say you confused me even more. Could you explain it from scratch as the answer? We've figured out that $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2/A_3\times \{0\}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and so it has three non-identity elements of order 2. So it's elements are $\{(e,0)N,(a,0)N,(a,1)N,(e,1)N,\}$ where $a\in S_3$ of order $2$ and $N=A_3\times\{0\}$. So the corresponding subgroups of $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2/A_3\times \{0\}$ are $\langle (a,0) N\rangle $, $\langle (a,1) N\rangle $ and $\langle (e,1) N\rangle $.

Comment: And these corresponding subgroups are $\langle(a,0)N \rangle=S_3\times \{0\}$, $\langle(e,1)N \rangle =A_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\langle(a,1)N \rangle=(aA_3,1)\cup (A_3,0)$, right?

Comment: I am sure that this is true. But i have spent huge amount of time in order to understand it :/

Answer (score 1):

Using Sylow-theory, it is easy to see that $S_3$ only has one normal subgroup of order 3 - namely $A_3$. Now it has no normal subgroup of order two, since then $S_3$ would be the direct product of $Z_2$ and $Z_3$ and hence cyclic. Now it should be easy to check that your three series are the only composition series since $Z_2$ has no non-trivial normal subgroup.

For these kinds of questions, the Jordan-Hölder theorem is often useful. It tells us that every composition series has the same length (in your case 3) and that the composition factors are unique up to isomorphism. In your case, two of your composition factors are isomorphic to $Z_2$ and one is isomorphic to $Z_3$. This should also be sufficient to answer your question.